# Submit form only after ajax verification success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm trying to have an "add to cart" button only perform an actual submit (proceed to an added-to-cart page) if an ajax call comes back successful, otherwise display a message given in the ajax result and not actually perform the submit.

this is what i have so far

```
$("#addtocart").submit(function(event){
    var data = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/cart/check",
        dataType:"json",
        data: data
    }).done(function(data){ 
        $("#message").html(data.message);              
        if (data.success == true) this.submit();         
    })
    event.preventDefault();         
});
```

if I remove event.preventDefault() the form always submits regardless of the check, if i leave it in, it never submits. Maybe this.submit() is not the right solution. I read somewhere that preventdefault should only be called if there was no success on the validation, but if i try

```
if (data.success == false) event.preventDefault();
```

it still submits the form no matter if data.success is true or false

i'd be ever so thankful if someone has a solution on how to do this right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` inside the done callback is the jqXhr object not the form, if you want to bind the form as the context of the done function use the `context config.

```
$.ajax({
    context: this, //<-- the form
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` is not your form inside the callback, because this is usually set to the context of the caller, which is jQuery's code, not yours, for that callback. There are a few different ways that you can fix it:

Use the `context` property of `$.ajax` to set `this` in your callback to whatever you want it to be - probably `this` for you:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    context: this
})
```

Use `$("#addtocart")` instead of `this`. However, that is less extensible if you change your mind about the selector that you use, or you want to use the same code for multiple different forms.

Use `event.target` (or `$(event.target)`) to run code on the event's target, whatever element it happens to be. This means that you can still access the jQuery XHR object through `this` if you decide that you still want to use it, though that might not matter to you at all.